# How to prove this relation between characteristic polynomials?

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

The problem wich I need an is idea to find an answer is below:

> Prove  that if the graph $H$ is obtained from the graph $G$ by subdividing the edge $uv$ then $$P_H(x)=P_G(x)+(x-1)P_{G-uv}(x)-P_{G-u}(x)-P_{G-v}(x)+P_{G-u-v}(x).$$

Subdividing edge $uv$ means adding vertex $t$, edges $tu$ and $tv$ morethere deleting $uv$.

I will be happy if you tell me about your knowledge.

Comment: The fact that you weren't able to submit a question with the title you wanted should have been an indication that it probably wasn't specific enough (no one will know what you are asking about from the title "The characteristic polynomial").

Comment: Since you are new, I want to give some advice about the site: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far**. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself. Lastly, some would consider your post rude because it is a command ("Prove"), not a request for help, so please consider rewriting it.